# Type mismatch error in Listview Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to pull all the data from excel sheet and display on listview3. While running below code, I am getting an error 'run time error 13" and 'type mismatch'.
Please advise as to what all changes are required.

```
Dim myFileNameDir As String
Dim wksSource As Worksheet
   Dim rngData As Range
   Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim LstItem As listItem
    Dim RowCount As Long
   Dim ColCount As Long
   Dim I As Long
  Dim j As Long

 myFileNameDir = Sheet1.Range("V3").Value & TextBox40.Text & ".xlsx"

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFileNameDir, UpdateLinks:=0
    Set wksSource = Worksheets("Sheet1")

       Set rngData = wksSource.Range("A1").CurrentRegion



        For Each rngCell In rngData.Rows(1).Cells
        Me.ListView3.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:=rngCell.Value, Width:=90
    Next rngCell
       RowCount = rngData.Rows.Count
    ColCount = rngData.Columns.Count
        For I = 2 To RowCount
       Set LstItem = ListView3.ListItems.Add(Text:=rngData(I, 1).Value)
      For j = 2 To ColCount
         LstItem.ListSubItems.Add Text:=rngData(I, j).Value
    Next j
   Next I
```

Comment: What line number causes error? Does it compile? It seems odd that your ListItem is not capitalized in `Dim LstItem As listItem` - might suggest that it's not found the correct reference to the object

Comment: Error is on Set LstItem = ListView3.ListItems.Add(Text:=rngData(I, 1).Value)

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment

> It seems odd that your ListItem is not capitalized in

```
Dim LstItem As listItem
```

> this might suggest that it's not found the correct reference to
>   the object

As simple first attempt at `Debug | Compile` will show you that this is not a valid defined type.

If you don't know what the correct object type is you can try `Dim LstItem As Object`